# In R, duplicate argument names in function and function within the function. How can I pass an argument directly to dot dot dot?

Tags: r, expression, environment, rlang

In this case, how might I pass an argument directly to the dot dot dot in R?  Without changing the functions, and preferably not relying on position  E.g.

```
fun_inner <- function(other_arg = NA, a){
  print(paste("inner:", a))
  a
}

fun_outer <- function(a, ...){
  outer <- a
  print(paste("outer:", a))

  inner <- fun_inner(...)

  paste("inner not equal to outer?", inner != outer)
}
```

e.g. something like this... but this obviously does not work

```
fun_outer(a = 1, ... = list(a = 2))
```

Again, constraints being that I'd prefer to only modify the inputted arguments (rather than rewriting these functions)

```
# e.g. could create wrapper function for `fun_outer()` to call  
# that has w/ different names (or other analagous approach), 
# but would rather avoid...
fun_inner_wrapper <- function(other_arg, b){
  fun_inner(other_arg = other_arg, a = b)
}
```

and would also prefer not to rely simply on argument position.

```
# e.g. this inputs different values for `a` argument for `fun_inner()` and
# `fun_outer()`, but is reliant on giving a positional input for `other_arg` which I
# would prefer not to do...
fun_outer(1, 2, 3)
[1] "outer: 1"
[1] "inner: 3"
[1] "inner not equal to outer? TRUE"
```

Comment: What are you REALLY trying to do?

Comment: You can't pass two different parameters named `a` in the same function call in R. You're going to have to write a wrapper or change the internals of one of the functions. I'm not sure why you are trying so hard to avoid that. It often makes the most sense in a functional language like R to write a function to solve your problem.

Comment: You are both right :-( :-(  .  i opened another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58722758/how-to-specify-firefox-browser-version-for-rseleniumrs-driver) with what I actually need to do.  The question above is a curiosity that came-up + a hacked approach (and unlikely to work) solution for getting the linked question fixed...